# Angular2 - serious issues with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

First of all I'm just really disappointed how undocumented is the whole checkbox section. This is causing me some serious issues. I'd like to provide an array of strings that user can click and the selected strings get stored to a property. If then user decides to EDIT the current item, he can uncheck and check some other values and updates the values in the array. Sounds simple? It's a nightmare.

This is what I've come up with: https://plnkr.co/edit/FECAKFDRyMn8CyV4SpqD?p=preview

The steps are as follows: write a new name, select English and German and press "Add new". Then select "James" and uncheck "English" and press "Update" and you'll see that all languages have been removed. I have no idea if I'm even approaching correctly to this issue of checkboxes, there just isn't any documentation.

Code:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const LANG: any[] = [
  {label: 'English'},
  {label: 'German'},
  {label: 'Italian'}
]

class Person {
  constructor(public name:string; public speaking: string[]) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './src/app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./src/app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  people: Person[];
  person: Person = new Person('', []);
  languages: string[] = LANG;

  constructor() {
    let person1 = new Person('James', [Object.assign({}, LANG[0]), Object.assign({}, LANG[2])]);  
    let person2 = new Person('Frank', [Object.assign({}, LANG[1]));  
    this.people = [person1, person2];
  }

  AddNew(): void {
    this.person.speaking = this.languages.filter(x => x.selected === true);
    this.people.push(this.person);
    this.person = new Person('', []);
  }

  Reset(): void {
    this.person = new Person('', []);
  }

  Update(): void {
    this.person.speaking = this.languages.filter(x => x.selected === true);
  }

  Edit(name: string): void {
    this.person = this.people.find(x => x.name === name);
  }

  checkCondition(current: any): boolean {
    return (this.person.speaking.find((x: any) => x.label === current.label) !== undefined);
  }  

}
```

HTML:

```
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form #form>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.name" name="name" placeholder="insert name" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Languages:</label>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let language of languages">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="language.selected" name="languages" [checked]="checkCondition(language)" />{{language.label}}
      </label>        
    </li>
    {{languages |json}}
  </ul>
  <br /><br />
  <button (click)="Update()">Update</button> | 
  <button (click)="AddNew(); form.reset()">Add new</button> |
  <button (click)="Reset(); form.reset()">Reset form</button>
</form>

<hr />

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let one of people">
    {{one.name}}, speaking: {{one.speaking | json}} | <a href="#" (click)="Edit(one.name)">Edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thx for providing functioning debug example! In the debug, the language check is made on the `selected` field, while you can read below that original `Person` objects are created without this field

Comment: well, I have been playing with that plunker, the main issue here is the form.reset().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by approaching a bit different. Thanks anyway for your input.

Sample HTML code:

```
<li *ngFor="let language of languages">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"
      [checked]="checkCondition(language.label)"
      (change)="updateCheckedOptions(language, $event)" />
      {{language.label}}
  </label>        
</li>
```

The solution can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/OXXbt8jxZHzjB3jVYC0o?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main problems with your code:

First - you must create a copy each time you create a new item (instead of just referencing all your items to one object in memory). So inside your `AddNew` method please use

```
this.people.push(Object.assign(new Person(), this.person));
```

Second - this line:

```
this.languages.filter(x => x.selected === true);
```

is wrong because `this.languages` only contains the labels (without the selected property) and that is why you are resetting the selected languages while editing

Comment: actually he pushes them in an array, which is allright, but he's not managing well how the displayed object is linked to items IMO, it should be a sample copy that is actually displayed,

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your feedback. Could you perhaps provide a hint how to solve the problem with the editing of languages?

Comment: first - the type of language should be an object - maybe you intend to create a custom class for that?

Comment: Do i need a class in order to use checkboxes? Seems a bit bloated

Comment: @uglycode no, you have to think again your approach, the `selected` field obviously belongs to the interface, the form, not to a `Person` object the way you seem to want it. You could use a form object and copy the properties to your `Person` objects on editing for example

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your code, I found, that the main issue is, that you are using the checkbox values as part of your person object (you copy a reference to person.speaking).

You can see this in the AddNew function:

- Add "Willy" as person with all languages selected
- Add "Wonkers" as person with only one language selected
- Check the person.speaking array of "Willy": Only the language of "Wonkers" is selected.

When creating a new person, you copy the references of the selected values with filter, but you need to clone the objects.

(I am sure no JS wizzard, but this fixed the issue on add:)

```
  AddNew(): void {
    this.person.speaking = this.languages
                               .map(x =>  (x.selected===true)
                                             ? {label:x.label, selected:x.selected}
                                             : undefined)
                               .filter(x => x!==undefined);
    this.people.push(this.person);
    this.person = new Person('', []);
  }
```